# Cascade deletion of an object that can be related to itself

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, constraints

In my database, I have a number of objects that can be related to each other.

This is fine, until I decide I want to delete these objects. Because of the relation record, I need to implement cascade delete to prevent an exception from being thrown.

When an object that is on either side of the relation is deleted, I want the relation record to be deleted too. I would like to create a database structure that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyObject]
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     ...
);

CREATE TABLE [MyObjectRelation]
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     [MyObjectID] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [MyObject] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
     [RelatedMyObjectID] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [MyObject] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

However, whenever I attempt to run this on my database, I receive this error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint '...' on table 'MyObjectRelation' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I have read the documentation about this, but I do not see how this layout could cause a cycle. It is entirely possible of course, that I have misinterpreted the documentation on MSDN for cascade delete, and the database layout above will not achieve what I want here.

I would be very interested in hearing what I can do to implement the behaviour that I want.

Comment: The error message doesn't convey the full set of circumstances in which it will complain. The docs do say "The series of cascading referential actions triggered by a single DELETE or UPDATE must form a *tree* that contains no circular references. *No table can appear more than one time in the list of all cascading referential actions that result from the DELETE or UPDATE.* "

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that. So is the only way I can implement the behaviour that I want is to do it in the application itself? That's totally OK, but I'd just like to explore doing it in the database layer first.

Comment: All I personally can think of is having no `DELETE CASCADE` FKs, and in their place have an `ON DELETE` trigger on `MyObject`. But triggers are so unpleasant that I really hope there is another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive this error message because in SQL Server, **a table cannot appear more than one time** in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement. For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions tree.

You can use triggers to achieve the same behavior.